# Transformation of a variable

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, confidence-interval, inference, lognormal-distribution

Suppose I have a stochastic variable $X,$ that is not normally distributed using Shapiro Wilk test. Than I transform the variable using log transformation, and now the log transformation is normally distributed. How does performing hypothesis tests and constructing confidence interval affect my results, and is it possible to perform test on example a mean? How does the interpretation of the results change?

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Estimation_of_parameters) on estimation of parameters of the lognormal distribution. Or, perhaps, simply estimate using the transformed (now-normal) data.

Comment: Failure to reject $H_0$ in a test of normality does not give you any basis to claim that you have normality; any number of non-normal population distributions will always fit the data at least as well, which would leave you (if you had tested those distributions as well) with several distributions all of which you would fail to reject. They cannot all simultaneously be the distribution of the population from which the data were drawn.  A better conclusion is that you failed to rule out the normal (which is to say, in almost every case, that you simply made a type II error)